# IDE doesn't recognize the method

Tags: c++, dictionary, hash, qt-creator, code-completion

I'm trying to acces the cityMethod() inside the class City.

```
class City
{
    void cityMethod() { }
}
```

So, I do:

```
map<string,City> mymap;
City c;
mymap["Madrid"] = c;
```

Now, when I do this:

```
mymap["Madrid"].cityMethod();
```

Ok, it works. But the IDE(Qt) doesn't recognize the "cityMethod".
Am I doing something wrong? Is that compiler issue?

Comment: Technically (and nitpicking), the IDE is not Qt, but [QtCreator](http://www.qt.io/ide/). And your problem have nothing to do with the compiler, but the IDE that apparently can't handle such data-types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature does not seem to be supported by Qt Creator. There's an open [issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-8922) about it on http://bugreports.qt.io/.

It does work when using the `ClangCodeModel` plugin though. To use it, go to Help > About Plugins and activate the plugin there:

[image]

Then, enable its use in the options. Tools > Options > C++ > Code Model

[image]

You might experience performance issues with the Clang code model, but it does work:

[image]

Comment: I did everything you said and restarted the IDE, but it didn't solve.

Comment: Maybe the file you're editing is a header? Try switching everything to Clang, not just `C++` like in the screenshot.

Comment: No, it's not a header. I'm editing the main. I changed everything to Clang and didn't solve again. Do you have other idea?

Comment: I don't, sorry. You could check if the plugin is loaded correctly by looking for the green check mark next to it in the `About Plugins` dialog. But on the other hand, you probably wouldn't be able to select it in the options if it failed loading.

Comment: Anyway, I'm grateful by your answer.